# Return records that match all the supplied parameters skip if list is null

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to search a list by filter list criteria.

For example, I have the list of contact_id, names, states, and cities, as a list of strings.

```
public async Task<List<ContactRequestListModel>> SearchByMultipleAsync(
    List<string> contact_id, 
    List<string> email,
    List<string> phone, 
    List<string> name, 
    List<string> accountnumber, 
    List<string> city, 
    List<string> state)
{


var line = (from x in filtered
            where city.Contains(x.City)
         || contact_id.Contains(x.Id.ToString())
         || state.Contains(x.State)
         || name.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName ?? "" + " " + x.LastName) select x).ToList();

return line;
}
```

The above LINQ query is returning all the records that match any of the parameters passed. It is also returning the records where `city` and `states` are matched but records having no matching `contact_id`

How to search for the records that match all the supplied parameters, and if the supplied list of parameters is empty or not found it should skip the search.

Comment: `(city == null || city.Contains(x.City))`? We skip `city` if it's `null` and want match if it's not `null`

Comment: list could be empty but not null

Comment: `(city.Count <= 0 || city.Contains(x.City))` then? We skip city if it's empty and want match when it has values

Comment: there are only records with contact_id = 61, but it is returning two records because it is matched with city and state.

Comment: if you want just one record with `contact_id = 61` that has required  city *and* state, combine conditions with `&&` instead of `||` or put each condition in its own `where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to filter by presence of filter:

```
    public class ContactRequestSearchRequest
    {
        public List<string> ContactIds { get; set; }
        public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
        public List<string> Phones { get; set; }
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
        public List<string> AccountNumbers { get; set; }
        public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
        public List<string> States { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task<List<ContactRequestListModel>> SearchAsync(ContactRequestSearchRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var query = filtered.AsQueryable();
        if (request.ContactIds != null)
            query = query.Where(x => request.ContactIds.Contains(x.Id));
        if (request.Emails != null)
            query = query.Where(x => request.Emails.Contains(x.mail.address));

        //all other filterings...

        if (request.Names != null)
            query = query.Where(x => request.Names.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName ?? "" + " " + x.LastName));

        return await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

There is two reasons to this:

- As you see, they are similar, later if properties replaced, it will be easy to refactor to common methods, like `FilterBy`
- EF query is stupid, if you include something in it, it will still generate garbage like `1=1`, killing query plan and performance. So it is better to check in code BEFORE you add something to query.

Considering your use-case

> suppose if I try to filter with state, city and didn't pass the name, the list returned will be empty

Its not clear what you want, if you want to return nothing if ANY of your filters is null/empty - then just check it in beginning of the function:

```
        if (request.ContactIds == null && !request.ContactIds.Any() || 
            request.Emails == null || !request.Emails.Any() ||
            ...)
            return new List<ContactRequestListModel>();
```

Comment: isn't there any way to do all the filters in one line? without the multiple if conditions?

Comment: No. Why do you want to do it anyway? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: i found some drawbacks in your query when i have to use the string.join in with name like this `.Where(x => (name?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 ||
   name.Contains(string.Join(" ", new string[] {
     x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName}
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
 ));` it cann't be converted to expression tree.

Comment: Its not my drawback, its general approach to IQueryable. EF can't support anything and don't have/need SQL equivalent of everything in C#, so if you want something specific in query, for instance transformation/RPC/calculation - just make it outside of query and use result inside the query. Make your query look as simple as possible, without woo-doo transformations in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this:

```
var line = filtered
  .Where(x => (city?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 || city.Contains(x.City))
  .Where(x => (state?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 || state.Contains(x.State))
  .Where(x => (name?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 || name.Contains($"{x.FirstName} {x.MiddleName} {x.LastName}"))
  .ToList();
```

with a typical pattern

```
x => (city?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 || city.Contains(x.City)
```

where we skip `city` filtering if `city` is null or empty, otherwise we require match. You can add as many `Where` is required (one for each list to compare with).

For `name` filtering I kept your current implemantation, but, please, note, that if record *doesn't have* `MiddleName` the combined name will have *double* space:

```
John  Smith
```

To get rid of *double spaces* you can *join* names which are not empty:

```
string.Join(" ", new string[] {
   x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName}
  .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
```

I.e.

```
.Where(x => (name?.Count ?? 0) <= 0 ||
   name.Contains(string.Join(" ", new string[] {
     x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName}
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
 ));
```

Comment: for middlename `{MiddleName ?? ""}` could do correct right? to for avoiding double spaces?

Comment: joining the name is the best one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use and (`&&`) instead of or (`||`)

```
var line = (from x in filtered
            where city.Contains(x.City)
         && contact_id.Contains(x.Id.ToString())
         && state.Contains(x.State)
         && name.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName ?? "" + " " + x.LastName) select x).ToList();

if (line == null)
    //do what you want
else
    return line;
```

Comment: no it won't work it will return the list empty if any of the parameters is null

Comment: You are looking solution for returning data or passing parameters ?

Comment: i want to filter with the list of multiple string

Comment: suppose if i try to filter with state, city and didn't pass the name, the list returned will be empty

Comment: So, check list count first and then apply. Like `(name.Count != 0 && name.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName ?? "" + " " + x.LastName) )`

Comment: This will work, I guess you are having problem with `List<string> name` argument passed to method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var line = (from x in filtered
            where (!city.Any() || city.Contains(x.City))
            && (!contact_id.Any() || contact_id.Contains(x.Id.ToString()))
            && (!state.Any() || state.Contains(x.State))
            && name.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName ?? "" + " " + x.LastName) 
            select x).ToList();

return line;
```